# Передача данных из представления в контроллер ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

Мне нужно передать данные из представления в контроллер и затем передать другому представлению. При получении данных из представления я получаю все значения равные 0. Помогите пожалуйста разобраться в чем проблема.

Контроллер:

```
public class CalculationController: Controller
{
    private readonly ICalculationParameters calculationParameters;
    private Parameters pam = new Parameters();

    public CalculationController(ICalculationParameters calculationParameters)
    {
        this.calculationParameters = calculationParameters;
    }

    public IActionResult CalculationParameters()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CalculationParameters(Parameters pam)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            calculationParameters.Calculation(pam);
            return RedirectToAction("CalculationSize");
        }
        return View(pam);
    }

    public IActionResult CalculationSize(Parameters pam)
    {
        CalculationOfParameters calPam = new CalculationOfParameters(pam);
        return View(calPam.parameters);
    }
}
```

Представления из которого берутся данные вводимые пользователем:

```
@model Parameters

<div class="content">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <div class="block_content">
            <form asp-action="CalculationParameters" method="post">
                <table align="center" class="content_fields">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Напряжение питания инвертора</label>
                                    <div class="col-12">
                                        <input asp-for="En" class="form-control" />
                                        <span asp-validation-for="En" class="text-danger"></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Внешняя нагрузка</label>
                                    <div class="col-12">
                                        <input asp-for="Cn" class="form-control" />
                                        <span asp-validation-for="Cn" class="text-danger"></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Высокий уровень входного напряжения</label>
                                    <div class="col-12">
                                        <input asp-for="Uvh1" class="form-control" />
                                        <span asp-validation-for="Uvh1" class="text-danger"></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Толщина диэлектрика</label>
                                    <div class="col-12">
                                        <input asp-for="hd" class="form-control" />
                                        <span asp-validation-for="hd" class="text-danger"></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Низкий уровень входного напряжения</label>
                                    <div class="col-12">
                                        <input asp-for="Uvh0" class="form-control" />
                                        <span asp-validation-for="Uvh0" class="text-danger"></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Время включения</label>
                                    <div class="col-12">
                                        <input asp-for="t" class="form-control" />
                                        <span asp-validation-for="t" class="text-danger"></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Высокий уровень выходного напряжения</label>
                                    <div class="col-12">
                                        <input asp-for="Uvyh1" class="form-control" />
                                        <span asp-validation-for="Uvyh1" class="text-danger"></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Диэлектрическая проницаемость диэлектрика</label>
                                    <div class="col-12">
                                        <input asp-for="Ed" class="form-control" />
                                        <span asp-validation-for="Ed" class="text-danger"></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Низкий уровень выходного напряжения</label>
                                    <div class="col-12">
                                        <input asp-for="Uvyh0" class="form-control" />
                                        <span asp-validation-for="Uvyh0" class="text-danger"></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Подвижность электронов</label>
                                    <div class="col-12">
                                        <input asp-for="u" class="form-control" />
                                        <span asp-validation-for="u" class="text-danger"></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Пороговое напряжение</label>
                                    <div class="col-12">
                                        <input asp-for="U0" class="form-control" />
                                        <span asp-validation-for="U0" class="text-danger"></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Рассчитать" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </form>
        </div>
    </table>
</div>
```

Класс CalculationOfParameters (здесь проводится расчет параметров по значениям полученным из представления):

```
public class CalculationOfParameters
{
    public Parameters parameters = new Parameters();

    public CalculationOfParameters(Parameters pam)
    {
        this.parameters = pam;

        parameters.K = Math.Pow(1 - parameters.Uvyh0 / (parameters.En - parameters.U0), 2) / (2 * (parameters.Uvh1 - parameters.U0) 
            / (parameters.En - parameters.U0) *
            parameters.Uvyh0 / (parameters.En - parameters.U0) - Math.Pow(parameters.Uvyh0 / (parameters.En - parameters.U0), 2));
        parameters.wn_ln = (2 * parameters.hd * Math.Pow(10, -9) * parameters.Cn * Math.Pow(10, -12)) /
            (8.85 * Math.Pow(10, -12) * parameters.Ed * parameters.u * Math.Pow(10, -4) * parameters.t * Math.Pow(10, -6) * 
            (parameters.En - parameters.U0 - parameters.Uvyh1));
        parameters.wk_lk = parameters.K * parameters.wn_ln;
    }
}
```

Представление CalculationSize в которое передаются данные полученные в классе CalculationOfParameters:

```
@model Parameters

<h3>Результаты</h3>
<p>
    <font>
        Отношение крутизны характеристики ключевого МДП транзистора к соответствующей характеристике нагрузочного МДП транзистора Kк / Kн = @Model.K
    </font>
</p>
<p>
    <font>
        Отношение wн / lн для нагрузочного МДП транзистора = @Model.wn_ln
    </font>
</p>
<p>
    <font>
        Отношение wk / lk для ключевого МДП транзистора = @Model.wk_lk
    </font>
</p>
<p>
    <font>
        Введите минимально возможные при данной технологии значения lк и wн
    </font>
</p>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <div class="block_content">
        <form asp-action="CalculationParameters" method="post">
            <table align="center" class="content_fields">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Длина ключевого транзистора</label>
                                <div class="col-12">
                                    <input asp-for="lk" class="form-control" />
                                    <span asp-validation-for="lk" class="text-danger"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Ширина нагрузочного транзистора</label>
                                <div class="col-12">
                                    <input asp-for="wn" class="form-control" />
                                    <span asp-validation-for="wn" class="text-danger"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </form>
    </div>
</table>
```

Comment: У вас ```return RedirectToAction("CalculationSize")``` без параметров. Попробуйте так: ```RedirectToAction("CalculationSize", pam)```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло